# I have modified in config file. still i getting the error

Tags: mysql

I get this error... #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have set username and password as 'root'. and i have use xampp server

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
```

Comment: Can you connect from the command line with `mysql -u root -proot`? And, **which** config file? Which application are you using? BTW: `using password: NO` indicates that your application does not pass a password to mysql

Comment: _$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;_ then how can you connect the mysql with out password. Please try to connect to the mysql server as #Andreas requested to do.